# How to calculate the highest product of two consecutive array elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to calculate the maximum product from multiplying two values of an ascending index position i.e. `a[0]*a[1]` or `a[1]*a[2]`. The actual returned result needs to be the highest possible absolute value of this function called on each item:

```js
const adjacentElementsProduct = (array) => {
  let maxProduct = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const result = array[i] * array[i + 1];
    if (result > maxProduct) {
      maxProduct = result
    }
  }
  return maxProduct;
}
```

Now this seems to return the desired result when working with positive integers, but I'm struggling to understand how this could also work for negative ones. My understanding of arrays is fairly superficial at this point, so a good explanation would be most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This also works for negative numbers. Or do you want to get the highest absolute value?

Comment: If all products are negative this will return zero, not the highest negative value.

Answer (score 3):

> now this seems to return the desired results when working with positive integers, but I'm struggling to understand how this could also work for negative ones

Exactly the same way. -1 is "higher" than -5.

If you want the lowest value in an array of negative numbers instead, just change your `>` to `<`.

If you want the highest *absolute* value in an array of both positive and negative numbers, , then just change your `>` to a `<` if the array is all negative numbers, use `const result = Math.abs(array[i] * array[i + 1]);` and continue comparing with `>`.

Comment: Or if the highest absolute value should still be negative: `if (Math.abs(result) > Math.abs(maxProduct)) {`